# AWS S3 GET pre-signed url fails with CORS intermittently

Tags: java, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I'm generating a pre-signed url using java for an image stored in s3

```
  public String generateDownloadLink(String bucketName, String responseContentDisposition,
      String key, int days) {

    GetObjectRequest objectRequest =
        GetObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .responseContentDisposition(responseContentDisposition)
            .key(key).build();

    GetObjectPresignRequest preSignRequest =
        GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
            .signatureDuration(Duration.ofDays(days))
            .getObjectRequest(objectRequest)
            .build();

    PresignedGetObjectRequest presignedRequest = this.s3Presigner.presignGetObject(preSignRequest);

    return presignedRequest.url().toString();
```

The FE (react) then loads the image using an image tag as in the image below.
This modal [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal-image) also has a download button when opened in full screen -> the `a` tag element.
If the download button is pressed, it won't download anything because of a CORS error.

This [post](https://serverfault.com/a/856948) explains why, though the solution can't be applied in my case.

Also, this happens intermittently and i can't figure out what is different in those cases.
Sometimes I can see the thumbnail (aka the library does an initial GET to load the image and display it) and also after the modal is opened, I can download the image (aka the libray does another get with the `a` tag).

[image]

Bucket CORS config

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:3000",
            "https://<my-host>"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
```

Edit:
I can't add `crossorigin="anonymous"` because i don't have access to the img element

Comment: Are you on windows? Are you behind of some proxy, antivirus, etc ? Try from different devices, on different networks. Use [pure js ajax](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/6b6f2c0d052253f7b76a35427bdff1b9) to test if the same error occurs.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a race condition cause by browser caching. Try setting the [`crossorigin` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#crossorigin) in your image tag.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to open the CORS policy up completely, if it begins to work then you can start to refine the access until you realize where the issue is:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "*"
         
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

This is also a good blog on CORS which may help:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/deep-dive-into-cors-configs-on-aws-s3-how-to/

You can also try adding `crossorigin` param to your image tag:

```
<img src="my-img.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/img.png"
  crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force the browser to make the img tag use a CORS request when loading by setting the [crossorigin attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#crossorigin):

```html
<img src="foo.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bar/baz"
  crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

This stops the browser from treating the image as "tainted", but should also force s3 to return the appropriate CORS response that can be properly cached by the browser.

Comment: I can't do that because i don't have access to the img element

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `OPTIONS` to the list of `AllowedMethods` in your CORS config. The CORS preflight request made from the browser(before the "real" request) uses `OPTIONS` http method, so it needs to be allowed.

Comment: allowed_methods - (Required) Set of HTTP methods that you allow the origin to execute. Valid values are GET, PUT, HEAD, POST, and DELETE.